# How to validate an etherum address (go)?

Tags: golang, public-key

I'm looping through various addresses and I need to know which ones are BTC addresses and which are ETH addresses. So far I just check if the address is hex encoded. Is this function safe to use?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    key := "1DfjCuWDKRWpv1vGP9UNsb4ooArWnXfqnr"
    fmt.Println(isEther(key)) 
}

func isEther(s string) bool {
    s = strings.TrimPrefix(s, "0x")
    _, err := hex.DecodeString(s)
    if err == nil {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`types.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/afb8154eab2961996b321ac3fe5a21602e3b1aff/common/types.go#L150):

```
// IsHexAddress verifies whether a string can represent a valid hex-encoded
// Ethereum address or not.
func IsHexAddress(s string) bool {
    if hasHexPrefix(s) {
        s = s[2:]
    }
    return len(s) == 2*AddressLength && isHex(s)
}
```

You'll need to pull in the other called functions and variables, or redefine them in your own file.

There are other address-related utility functions in that file that might also be of use.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a regular expression to check if an Ethereum address is valid:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func IsValidAddress(v string) bool {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("^0x[0-9a-fA-F]{40}$")
    return re.MatchString(v)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(IsValidAddress("0x323b5d4c32345ced77393b3530b1eed0f346429d")) // true
    fmt.Println(IsValidAddress("0xXYZb5d4c32345ced77393b3530b1eed0f346429d")) // false
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/k3JqUnZBiKK

Comment: This method works for non-checksummed addresses, defined in EIP-55